# rows having partial matching data from the above row come to new column in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
No.  Name     userid
1    Ram      53
2    L-Ram    63
3    Aman     20
4    Joseph   50
5    2_Aman   66
6    Raj      33
7    name Raj 22 
8    Mohan mm 39
9    Mohan    67 
10   jj-Rahul 90
11   Rahul    95
```

So as you can see. some of the values in the second row are partially matching like `Ram` and `Aman`. I tried using `stringr` package in R for partial matching but I couldn't reach to the end point with it. I simply want output like this:

```
No.  Name     userid  id2
1    Ram      53      63          
2    Aman     20      66
3    Joseph   50
4    Raj      33      22
5    Mohan    39      67  
6    Rahul    90      95
```

I am unable to find any useful and straightforward solution. I am very new to R and just learning.

Comment: For this kind of problems you should really describe better what is actually considered a match. Is it always just a single letter / number and - / _ in the beginning, or something completely different?

Comment: @JamesZ you are right. Now I have added few more examples that covers all the types of cases in my data. I hope this will clear the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the prefix in 'Name' column and use `pivot_wider` to reshape to 'wide' format

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
    mutate(Name = str_remove_all(Name, '.*(?=[A-Z])|\\s+.*'),
           No. = str_c('userid', rowid(Name))) %>% 
    pivot_wider(names_from = No., values_from = userid)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
#  Name   userid1 userid2
#  <chr>    <int>   <int>
#1 Ram         53      63
#2 Aman        20      66
#3 Joseph      50      NA
#4 Raj         33      22
#5 Mohan       39      67
#6 Rahul       90      95
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(No. = 1:11, Name = c("Ram", "L-Ram", "Aman", "Joseph", 
"2_Aman", "Raj", "name Raj", "Mohan mm", "Mohan", "jj-Rahul", 
"Rahul"), userid = c(53L, 63L, 20L, 50L, 66L, 33L, 22L, 39L, 
67L, 90L, 95L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L
))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I had to update the problem since it was not covering all the cases. Your solution is working fine. Just few cases are not working and the result is not coming as expected. Please see the updated example list of the problem and just update your answer. I am very sorry for not being clear with the question the first time. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @Durdam thanks, I updated the post based on the new example